# ToDecimal Regional / Culture problems

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, oracle, cultureinfo

I'm receiving from the Oracle database the following value (as varchar): `7876,72`
In Visual Studio it's read as a `String`

**CASE 1 (expected case):**

When I'm debuggin I see: `7876.72` and when I try to `Convert.ToDecimal("7876.72")` I'm getting `7876.72D`

**CASE 2 (wrong case):**

When I'm debuggin I see: `7876,72` and when I try to `Convert.ToDecimal("7876,72")` I'm getting `787672D`

I'm checking the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` and `RegionInfo.CurrentRegion` and it's the same on both machines...

The main reason of this is because:

`Convert.ToDecimal("7876,72").ToString("0,0.00", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` gives me: `787,672.00` and it should be `7,876.72`.

**Global.asax - Application_Start**

```
Dim newCulture As CultureInfo = DirectCast(System.Threading.Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Clone(), CultureInfo)
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern = "yyyy/MM/dd"
newCulture.DateTimeFormat.DateSeparator = "/"
newCulture.NumberFormat.CurrencyDecimalSeparator = "."
newCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator = "."
Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = newCulture
```

Any ideas on how to keep the same value on both machines?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: what about `string.Replace(',', '.')` ?

Comment: Are you using the same oracle database in both cases, or are there different servers on the different machines?  Are you using ODBC?

Comment: @Trisped Same server. Using ado connection

Comment: @csharpler I can do that, but I preffer knowing what is the cause of the problem cause I'm getting a similar problem with dates

Comment: In that case I would check your connection string and the system's Region and Language settings in the control panel.  Also, I would try the query in other software (like a SQL Managment interface) to see if the results are the same.

Comment: Observe CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.NumberFormat.NumberDecimalSeparator on both clients.

Comment: @ErenErsönmez check my update, it's the same on both clients (verified on debug)

Comment: This is not a culture problem, this is a "using the wrong column type" problem.  Fix the dbase.

Comment: @HansPassant it's the return of a procedure and it cannot be changed. There should be a way of making all the clients behave the same way as case 1.

Comment: That's kinda nonsense, write another procedure that returns a number.  Patching around these fundamental problems just beget brittle systems that fall over unexpectedly and undiagnosably.

Comment: Ok, I didnt read the question carefully. If this is a varchar column and varchar columns have no concept of number formatting, then there is no way some clients are reading the exact same result with a comma instead of a dot. You're probably comparing two different values *written* by clients with different cultures.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the Oracle client, I had some inconsistency between my developer machine and the server machine, that was the main reason why the dates and the decimal values where showing differente on both machines.

[image: Error seeing locally, server and developer machine]

The solution was forcing both machines to behave the same way, and to do that we changed the key of the Oracle client and added the needed parameters:

[image]

Hope it helps someone else.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting the output mentioned above as not expected because the following value `7876,72` is equal to `787672`. The comma is just used to separate the numbers but it is not used to indicate a decimal point when converting. However, the decimal point is represented by the following character <kbd>`.`</kbd>

I'd recommend you to replace the character `,` with `.` since you would like to get a decimal point instead of `,`.

**Example**

```
string NumberFromDatabase = "7876,72"; //Initialize a new string of name NumberFromDatabase as 7876,72
string NumberAfterReplacement = NumberFromDatabase.Replace(',', '.'); //Initialize a new string of name NumberAfterReplacement as 7876.72
decimal Output = Convert.ToDecimal(NumberAfterReplacement); //Initialize a new decimal of name Output as 7876.72
```

Thanks,

I hope you find this helpful :)

Comment: It could be done like this, but since some clients are getting the correct value with a dot `.`, I would like to know what's making this issue...

Answer (score 0):

For numbers: Use `TryParse(...)` with an appropriate `NumberStyle`

For Dates: It's a good habit to `ParseExact`

Comment: This does not address the OP (different values from the same database).

Comment: Apparently OP is storing numbers and dates as string - in which case no one can help him anyway.

Comment: There are many logical ways to store numbers in a DB, not just two.  The OP is not asking how to validate the data, it is asking why two similar systems are getting a different result from the database.